# apache cxf throws "Error reading XMLStreamReader" for application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: spring-boot, cxf, content-type

I have implemented webservice using Springboot and apache cxf library.

If  header is set to **content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded** it throws an "Error reading XMLStreamReader".

It works if **content-type:application/xml.**

I have same webservice exposed on our legacy app which is old Spring and hosted in tomcat webserver, it accepts content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Springboot cxf library are on version 3.4.4 and old Spring app cxf is on 2.6.4 version.

**UPDATE** : When the I m send SOAP request using postman and header is set to **content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded** the request is empty , I added custom interceptor and tried to print the request and it is empty.

If i set header **content-type:application/xml.** I am able print full request in my customer interceptor.

Why with Springboot I am getting empty request when header is set to **content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

Below is the stacktrace:

```
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.796 2021-10-13 12:04:04,796 (3706595) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController - Service http request on thread: Thread[http-nio-8225-exec-2,5,main]
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.796 2021-10-13 12:04:04,796 (3706595) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination - Create a new message for processing
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.797 2021-10-13 12:04:04,797 (3706596) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Headers - Request Headers: {Accept=[*/*], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate], Authorization=[***], cache-control=[no-cache, no-cache], connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[3548], content-type=[application/x-www-form-urlencoded], cookie=[JSESSIONID=515326571A247E4AAA3606E5744BC014], host=[localhost:8225], postman-token=[c6a28c3a-194a-48c4-b021-3121145fc694], Proxy-Authorization=[***], user-agent=[West Wind Internet Protocols 6.17], x-amzn-trace-id=[Root=1-616531e1-251451d3146f266946c920eb], x-forwarded-for=[129.232.215.82], x-forwarded-port=[443], x-forwarded-proto=[https]}
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.797 2021-10-13 12:04:04,797 (3706596) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.transport.https.CertConstraintsInterceptor@1a0f004a to phase pre-stream
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.797 2021-10-13 12:04:04,797 (3706596) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@5d8a7c50 was created. Current flow:
  receive [PolicyInInterceptor, AttachmentInInterceptor]
  pre-stream [CertConstraintsInterceptor]
  post-stream [StaxInInterceptor]
  read [SAAJPreInInterceptor, WSDLGetInterceptor, ReadHeadersInterceptor, SoapActionInInterceptor, StartBodyInterceptor]
  pre-protocol [WSS4JInInterceptor, MustUnderstandInterceptor]
  post-protocol [CheckFaultInterceptor, JAXBAttachmentSchemaValidationHack]
  unmarshal [DocLiteralInInterceptor, SoapHeaderInterceptor]
  pre-logical [OneWayProcessorInterceptor]
  post-logical [WrapperClassInInterceptor]
  pre-invoke [SwAInInterceptor, HolderInInterceptor]
  invoke [ServiceInvokerInterceptor]
  post-invoke [OutgoingChainInterceptor]

[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.797 2021-10-13 12:04:04,797 (3706596) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInInterceptor@2f9d82b5
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.797 2021-10-13 12:04:04,797 (3706596) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentInInterceptor@3a852bdf
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.797 2021-10-13 12:04:04,797 (3706596) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.transport.https.CertConstraintsInterceptor@1a0f004a
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.797 2021-10-13 12:04:04,797 (3706596) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxInInterceptor@45ac5280
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.797 2021-10-13 12:04:04,797 (3706596) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxInEndingInterceptor@7225972d to phase pre-invoke
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.797 2021-10-13 12:04:04,797 (3706596) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@5d8a7c50 was modified. Current flow:
  receive [PolicyInInterceptor, AttachmentInInterceptor]
  pre-stream [CertConstraintsInterceptor]
  post-stream [StaxInInterceptor]
  read [SAAJPreInInterceptor, WSDLGetInterceptor, ReadHeadersInterceptor, SoapActionInInterceptor, StartBodyInterceptor]
  pre-protocol [WSS4JInInterceptor, MustUnderstandInterceptor]
  post-protocol [CheckFaultInterceptor, JAXBAttachmentSchemaValidationHack]
  unmarshal [DocLiteralInInterceptor, SoapHeaderInterceptor]
  pre-logical [OneWayProcessorInterceptor]
  post-logical [WrapperClassInInterceptor]
  pre-invoke [StaxInEndingInterceptor, SwAInInterceptor, HolderInInterceptor]
  invoke [ServiceInvokerInterceptor]
  post-invoke [OutgoingChainInterceptor]

[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.797 2021-10-13 12:04:04,797 (3706596) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor$SAAJPreInInterceptor@1c90e3c6
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.797 2021-10-13 12:04:04,797 (3706596) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor$SAAJPreInInterceptor@1c90e3c6
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.797 2021-10-13 12:04:04,797 (3706596) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxInInterceptor@45ac5280
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.797 2021-10-13 12:04:04,797 (3706596) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.transport.https.CertConstraintsInterceptor@1a0f004a
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.798 2021-10-13 12:04:04,798 (3706597) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentInInterceptor@3a852bdf
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.798 2021-10-13 12:04:04,798 (3706597) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInInterceptor@2f9d82b5
[WARN ] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.798 2021-10-13 12:04:04,798 (3706597) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] WARN  org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://soap.api.controller.web.****.com/}EnterpriseAPISoapService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error reading XMLStreamReader.
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor$SAAJPreInInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJInInterceptor.java:145) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor$SAAJPreInInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJInInterceptor.java:107) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:298) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:273) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239) [javamelody-core-1.83.0.jar:1.83.0]
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215) [javamelody-core-1.83.0.jar:1.83.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:701) ~[woodstox-core-6.2.6.jar:6.2.6]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2235) ~[woodstox-core-6.2.6.jar:6.2.6]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2141) ~[woodstox-core-6.2.6.jar:6.2.6]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1180) ~[woodstox-core-6.2.6.jar:6.2.6]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1203) ~[woodstox-core-6.2.6.jar:6.2.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor$SAAJPreInInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJInInterceptor.java:130) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    ... 62 more
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.798 2021-10-13 12:04:04,798 (3706597) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.ServerPolicyOutFaultInterceptor@17fd33dd to phase setup
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.798 2021-10-13 12:04:04,798 (3706597) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WebFaultOutInterceptor@686d836c to phase pre-protocol
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.798 2021-10-13 12:04:04,798 (3706597) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor@28963fe4 to phase prepare-send
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.798 2021-10-13 12:04:04,798 (3706597) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxOutInterceptor@70c3a941 to phase pre-stream
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.799 2021-10-13 12:04:04,799 (3706598) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor@ede1f5f to phase write
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.799 2021-10-13 12:04:04,799 (3706598) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentOutInterceptor@aac8b0b to phase pre-stream
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.799 2021-10-13 12:04:04,799 (3706598) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor@13dcfca5 to phase write
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.799 2021-10-13 12:04:04,799 (3706598) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor@7e38d63e to phase pre-logical
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.799 2021-10-13 12:04:04,799 (3706598) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultOutInterceptor@e21a41 to phase prepare-send
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.799 2021-10-13 12:04:04,799 (3706598) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@d6f3462 was created. Current flow:
  setup [ServerPolicyOutFaultInterceptor]
  pre-logical [SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor]
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor, Soap11FaultOutInterceptor]
  pre-stream [AttachmentOutInterceptor, StaxOutInterceptor]
  pre-protocol [WebFaultOutInterceptor]
  write [SoapOutInterceptor]

[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.799 2021-10-13 12:04:04,799 (3706598) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.ServerPolicyOutFaultInterceptor@17fd33dd
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.799 2021-10-13 12:04:04,799 (3706598) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.ServerPolicyOutFaultInterceptor - No binding operation info.
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.799 2021-10-13 12:04:04,799 (3706598) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor@7e38d63e
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.799 2021-10-13 12:04:04,799 (3706598) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor@28963fe4
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.799 2021-10-13 12:04:04,799 (3706598) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor@34d084e0 to phase prepare-send-ending
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.799 2021-10-13 12:04:04,799 (3706598) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@d6f3462 was modified. Current flow:
  setup [ServerPolicyOutFaultInterceptor]
  pre-logical [SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor]
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor, Soap11FaultOutInterceptor]
  pre-stream [AttachmentOutInterceptor, StaxOutInterceptor]
  pre-protocol [WebFaultOutInterceptor]
  write [SoapOutInterceptor]
  prepare-send-ending [MessageSenderEndingInterceptor]

[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.799 2021-10-13 12:04:04,799 (3706598) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultOutInterceptor@e21a41
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.799 2021-10-13 12:04:04,799 (3706598) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultOutInterceptor$Soap11FaultOutInterceptorInternal@62e5b97b to phase marshal
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.799 2021-10-13 12:04:04,799 (3706598) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@d6f3462 was modified. Current flow:
  setup [ServerPolicyOutFaultInterceptor]
  pre-logical [SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor]
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor, Soap11FaultOutInterceptor]
  pre-stream [AttachmentOutInterceptor, StaxOutInterceptor]
  pre-protocol [WebFaultOutInterceptor]
  write [SoapOutInterceptor]
  marshal [Soap11FaultOutInterceptorInternal]
  prepare-send-ending [MessageSenderEndingInterceptor]

[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.799 2021-10-13 12:04:04,799 (3706598) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentOutInterceptor@aac8b0b
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.799 2021-10-13 12:04:04,799 (3706598) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxOutInterceptor@70c3a941
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.800 2021-10-13 12:04:04,800 (3706599) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxOutEndingInterceptor@5362971 to phase pre-stream-ending
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.800 2021-10-13 12:04:04,800 (3706599) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@d6f3462 was modified. Current flow:
  setup [ServerPolicyOutFaultInterceptor]
  pre-logical [SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor]
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor, Soap11FaultOutInterceptor]
  pre-stream [AttachmentOutInterceptor, StaxOutInterceptor]
  pre-protocol [WebFaultOutInterceptor]
  write [SoapOutInterceptor]
  marshal [Soap11FaultOutInterceptorInternal]
  pre-stream-ending [StaxOutEndingInterceptor]
  prepare-send-ending [MessageSenderEndingInterceptor]

[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.800 2021-10-13 12:04:04,800 (3706599) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WebFaultOutInterceptor@686d836c
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.800 2021-10-13 12:04:04,800 (3706599) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor@ede1f5f
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.800 2021-10-13 12:04:04,800 (3706599) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor$SoapOutEndingInterceptor@6d3bed65 to phase write-ending
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.800 2021-10-13 12:04:04,800 (3706599) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@d6f3462 was modified. Current flow:
  setup [ServerPolicyOutFaultInterceptor]
  pre-logical [SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor]
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor, Soap11FaultOutInterceptor]
  pre-stream [AttachmentOutInterceptor, StaxOutInterceptor]
  pre-protocol [WebFaultOutInterceptor]
  write [SoapOutInterceptor]
  marshal [Soap11FaultOutInterceptorInternal]
  write-ending [SoapOutEndingInterceptor]
  pre-stream-ending [StaxOutEndingInterceptor]
  prepare-send-ending [MessageSenderEndingInterceptor]

[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.800 2021-10-13 12:04:04,800 (3706599) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultOutInterceptor$Soap11FaultOutInterceptorInternal@62e5b97b
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.800 2021-10-13 12:04:04,800 (3706599) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor$SoapOutEndingInterceptor@6d3bed65
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.800 2021-10-13 12:04:04,800 (3706599) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxOutEndingInterceptor@5362971
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.800 2021-10-13 12:04:04,800 (3706599) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor@34d084e0
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.801 2021-10-13 12:04:04,801 (3706600) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination - Finished servicing http request on thread: Thread[http-nio-8225-exec-2,5,main]
[DEBUG] 2021-10-13 12:04:04.801 2021-10-13 12:04:04,801 (3706600) [http-nio-8225-exec-2] [[]] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController - Finished servicing http request on thread: Thread[http-nio-8225-exec-2,5,main]
```

Comment: This link explains why request was empty, it is  HiddenHttpMethodFilter causing it . Detailed explain available at https://newbedev.com/why-is-httpservletrequest-inputstream-empty

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved .

When header Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded is added to  request to Springboot app ,request body is empty.

You need to disable HiddenHttpMethodFilter.

I followed instruction is below link and it worked.

https://newbedev.com/why-is-httpservletrequest-inputstream-empty